# How to get the structure of a module by ToolsAPI in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, structure, toolsapi

I want to get the structure information of a module (pascal unit) by ToolsAPI. just like the structure view of the IDE does.

Classes, Records, Interfaces, Variables/Constants, etc
Members, Parameters, etc.

Is there already an easy & efficient way to get these metadata?

Comment: The problem is, using ToolsApi you see uncompiled modules, so you need an "parser". Delphi has an (buggy) parser that runs withing the IDE but I'm not aware of a way to tap into it's results. +1 from me and a favorite.

Comment: It's my last choice to use a parser. It maybe cost me so much time but buggy...

Comment: +1 & add question as favourite: Completely agree with Cosmin Prund !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a [parser](http://code.google.com/p/castaliadelphiparser/) is not so bad idea?

Comment: Thank you. I am going to investigating on it.

Comment: Actually, this is the only way. It is exactly the reason that for instance http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html (Model Maker Code Explorer) and http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40552 (Delphi built-in-refactoring) have written their own parser (outside of the Delphi compiler).

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no way to query special structured information for a given file.

What you could do is to access the information in the Structure pane. That way requires the file to be the active module (can be achieved by the OTA), the output depends on the Structure pane settings (Tools | Options... -> Environment Options | Explorer) and if a node is a field, a procedure or whatever needs to be determined over the image index, parent...

This code walks through the Structure pane.

```
procedure StructureViewToSL(ASL: TStringList);

  procedure TreeToSL(ANode: IOTAStructureNode; ASL: TStringList; const APrefix: string);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    ASL.Add(APrefix + ANode.Caption);
    for I := 0 to ANode.ChildCount - 1 do
      TreeToSL(ANode.Child[I], ASL, APrefix + '  ');
  end;

var
  StructureView: IOTAStructureView;
  StructureContext: IOTAStructureContext;
  Node: IOTAStructureNode;
  I: Integer;
begin
  StructureView := BorlandIDEServices as IOTAStructureView;
  StructureContext := StructureView.GetStructureContext;
  for I := 0 to StructureContext.RootNodeCount - 1 do
  begin
    Node := StructureContext.GetRootStructureNode(I);
    TreeToSL(Node, ASL, '');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Uwe Schuster. This way appeared in my mind. but as you said, it only works when the module is active. What I am looking for is a way to support all modules in a project group.

Comment: With the OTA it is possible to enumerate all projects and modules of a project group and it is possible to make each module the active module.

Comment: yeah. Each module must be opened and active if I am not wrong. But it seems not the best way in my situation...

Comment: Is there a way to improve the piece of code given that Delphi (Compiler/RTL/Rtti/ToolsAPI) has undergone many changes since the date of the post ?